# How do I find the creation date of a document in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

How do I find the creation date of a document in MarkLogic?

I was hoping to find something like `xdmp:document-creation-date()`.

Answer (score 2):

MarkLogic will [maintain a last-modified timestamp](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/databases#id_77652) if you enable it in the database options (I think it's enabled by default), but for creation date you would need to track that on your own. A common pattern is to store that value in an attribute or in a document property when the document is inserted.

Comment: The last-modified timestamp is stored as a doc property, so storing creation timestamp there as well might make most sense. Last-modified used to be enabled by default, but they changed the default in ML6 or ML7, as it often created a lot of extra db fragments, that weren't really used.